# In MS Project 2010, is it possible to renumber the task ids?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

I'd like the task id field to increment in the same order as the start date, but I have added tasks between existing tasks, so when I sort by start date, the task ids go 1, 8, 15, 2, 4, 5, 7, etc.  This is not a big deal but it would just be nice if the task ids were consecutive.

Comment: When I sort by start date and have turned on Outline Number, I would like the Outline number to match the sort order. It looks strange to see 2.5, 2.1, 2.3. 2.2 when the start dates are sorted properly. Is there any way around this other than not check Outline Number under the Format Tab?

Comment: Hi Charles, welcome to PMSE! The Stack Exchange structure is question-answer oriented, so if you have a specific question, you should raise a new question instead of posting _another_ question as an answer.

Comment: Sorting is absolutely NOT the problem. It is that when first developing a schedule, tasks get moved around, added, deleted, etc. When you're ready to baseline, it would be nice to renumber them in the order you ended up with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I have found in most cases when the task IDs are listed non-sequentially (the numbers in the left column are out of order) it is because the task list has been sorted.  IF this is the case, you can open the Sort By dialog (Project | Sort | Sort By), select (place a check mark in) the Permanently Renumber Tasks option and click the sort button to renumber your tasks.
>
> Note that if your project IDs are out of order because the task list has been sorted, the sort options in the Sort By dialog should correspond to the way your tasks are currently sorted.  If for some reason this is not the case, sorting could mess up your carefully crafted task structure.  I STRONGLY RECOMMEND backing up (saving) your project before trying to sort or renumber your tasks.

I quote Bob Segrest, PMP
Microsoft Project Blackbelt

Comment: Note that in MS Project 2010, it's View->Sort->Sort By then check Permanently Renumber Tasks.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and found the following solution:
View -> Sort -> Sort by -> Unique ID

This puts it back into the original order.